# Facebook Audience Network SDK version 6.2.1 can't update

Tags: ios, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to update by cocoa pod but it shows [this](https://ibb.co/XDJNw9H) error.

```
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
pod install
```

Then I am trying to update manually from  [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/adding-sdk/ios/) link but the does not open. Can anyone help me! thanks in advance.